# How to document the javascript class method using jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Here is my JS class:

```
/**
 * QQ object
 * @date 8/16/2023 - 3:53:07 PM
 *
 * @export
 * @class QQ
 * @typedef {QQ}
 */
export default class QQ{
    /**
     * Creates an instance of QQ.
     * @date 8/16/2023 - 4:03:27 PM
     *
     * @constructor
     */
    constructor(){        
        /**
         * Method BB
         * @date 8/16/2023 - 3:53:23 PM
         */        
        this.bb=()=>{
            
        }
    }
}
```

Why the method bb does not be shown on the generated web page?

[image]

When I click on the "line 1" link, the browser just shows the source code of the QQ class.

How can I make the method b to be shown on the generated web page?